# MS SQL Select MAX Date Issue

Tags: php

I know that this is very similar to a lot of posts but I am attempting to writing a php query that connects to a Microsoft SQL Server. I can get it to bring all of the relevant data I want but when I put my where clause in the php query doesn't run. I have three tables

| MetalSource | MetalPrice | Currency |

In the metal prices table there is a date/time field which I want to find the latest date any date was put into the database regardless of time, how can this be done? My query is as follows:

```
$query = "SELECT mp.MetalSourceID, mp.UnitPrice, mp.DateCreated, mp.HighUnitPrice,
mp.PreviousUnitPrice, mp.PreviousHighUnitPrice, 
mp.MetalSourceName, cu.Currency FROM tblMetalPrice AS mp 
INNER JOIN tblMetalSource as ms ON mp.MetalSourceID = ms.MetalSourceID 
INNER JOIN tblCurrency AS cu ON ms.CurrencyID = cu.CurrencyID
WHERE
SELECT MAX (DateCreated)
FROM mp"
```

Like i've said the SELECT statement works perfectly fine, but when I am trying to reduce the results with my WHERE clause it seems to die.

I've looked at all the other posts and tried several different things but nothing seems to be getting what I need.

Thanks

Comment: You can't do a WHERE followed by a select like that - `WHERE DateCreated = (SELECT MAX (DateCreated)FROM mp)`

Comment: Thanks James works like a treat ... its a friday morning and my brains fried and funny thing about it I knew you couldn't follow a WHERE with a SELECT.

Comment: Hi James again ... your comments work but I have another problem. I want to be able to bring back all results from that last date but with it being a date/time database field its bringing just the last one back. Is there any ways of doing this so that it brings everyone back from that specific date no matter what time it was loaded to the database

Comment: Could you explain further... do you want all fields AFTER a certain date?

Comment: Basically the way the database works is I upload metal prices and they each have a ID 1 2 3 etc different names and it gives it a date/time stamp of when it was uploaded. I want to be able see ID  1 to 31 from the last time I did any upload.

Comment: Just to confirm, you upload 31 records every "week" and during upload you add in a "datetime" which is at the time of upload, you want the LAST batch of 1-31 ?

Comment: I do this every day as its market data and it adds in the "datetime" that is correct and I do want the last 31 records uploaded.

Comment: `ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 31`

Comment: So the query should be `$query = "SELECT tblMetalPrice.MetalSourceID, ROUND(tblMetalPrice.PriceInPounds,2), tblMetalPrice.UnitPrice, tblMetalPrice.HighUnitPrice, tblMetalPrice.PreviousUnitPrice, tblMetalPrice.PreviousHighUnitPrice, tblMetalSource.MetalSourceName, tblMetalSource.UnitBasis, tblCurrency.Currency from tblMetalPrice INNER JOIN tblMetalSource ON tblMetalPrice.MetalSourceID = tblMetalSource.MetalSourceID INNER JOIN tblCurrency ON tblMetalSource.CurrencyID = tblCurrency.CurrencyID  WHERE DateCreated = (SELECT MAX (DateCreated) FROM tblMetalPrice)ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 31" ;`

Comment: Remove the `WHERE DateCreated = (SELECT MAX (DateCreated) FROM tblMetalPrice)`

Comment: This still doesn't work. `$query = "SELECT tblMetalPrice.MetalSourceID, ROUND(tblMetalPrice.PriceInPounds,2), tblMetalPrice.UnitPrice,  tblMetalPrice.HighUnitPrice, tblMetalPrice.PreviousUnitPrice, tblMetalPrice.PreviousHighUnitPrice, tblMetalSource.MetalSourceName, tblMetalSource.UnitBasis, tblCurrency.Currency from tblMetalPrice INNER JOIN tblMetalSource ON tblMetalPrice.MetalSourceID = tblMetalSource.MetalSourceID INNER JOIN tblCurrency ON tblMetalSource.CurrencyID = tblCurrency.CurrencyID ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 31" ;` as you stated but it just connectsbut doesn't bring anything back

Comment: `datetime` needs to be changed to `DateCreated` - I was just paraphrasing at the time

Comment: Thanks ... this works apart from the LIMIT 31 ... if I exclude the limit 31 from the php query its runs fine as soon as I add it back in it dies ... any ideas.

Comment: The SQL is fine... I'm wondering if it's your script.

Comment: added the script below

Answer (score 0):

As per comments:

```
ORDER BY DateCreated DESC LIMIT 31
```

This will order the data and limit it by 31 rows.